# Automatically read video and trim

Tags: trim, social-gaming

So I am a gamer who loves editing videos and creating montages. I play a game called Apex Legends, and find that when editing long videos (Up to 5 hours long) I follow the same procedure every time. I skip ahead in the video until I see when I get a kill (Displayed in the top right of the screen as seen in picture below).

I then pause the video and begin the trimming process.

So my question is; Is there anything out there that can "read" videos? Assuming there is, is it possible to have a code that can read the screen, identify a change in kills, then trim say 5 seconds before and after that change? I am not asking anyone to write this code, but simply want to know if its possible
(Particularly with Python as that is my strongest language). Thank you all for your time and insight.

Comment: I apologize for not having a picture to display as the screenshot I had simply wont upload.

Comment: Not an expert in image analysis or machine learning. But I guess the process of converting videos to frames for detecting the kill score and also training your algorithm to find the kill score change correctly. It's possible but requires quite a lot of work. My opinion :|